# MKMapview not working correctly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

First, when I set the region map view, zoom in and zoom out work correctly. When I try to set the annotation with a custom view, and when I set the annotations,  zooming doesn't work. After the user zooms in, it will automatically zoom out.

See my code below:

```
       func setRegion(){
        var newRegion =  MKCoordinateRegion ()
        //        let str = String(format: "%.01f", maxLoc)
        //        maxdist = Double(str)!
        let subscriberData = (SubscriberConfigDBHandler.SubConfigDBSharedInstance).getSubscriberUserDetails()

        let latLanCoords :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:subscriberData.busLat as Double , longitude:subscriberData.busLng as Double)
        newRegion.center.latitude = latLanCoords.coordinate.latitude
        newRegion.center.longitude = latLanCoords.coordinate.longitude
        newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.075
        newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.075
        self.liveTrackingMapView.setRegion(newRegion, animated: false)

    }

    private var mapChangedFromUserInteraction = false

    private func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
        let view = self.liveTrackingMapView.subviews[0]
        if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
            for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
                if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        mapChangedFromUserInteraction = mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction()

    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {

        }
    }
    func  tapGesture(sender :UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender != tap1  {
            self.searchListTableView .removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    func navigationButtonTapped() {
        for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
            if controller.isKindOfClass(DashBoardViewController) {
                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller as UIViewController, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
    func getLiveLocationData() {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30, target: self, selector: #selector(getRefreshedLocationData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    func getRefreshedLocationData(){
        self.isFrom = "liveTracking"
        if vehicleMap.count > 0 {
            (SubscriberLocationService.sharedSubLocationService).sublocationDelegate = self
            (SubscriberLocationService.sharedSubLocationService).syncLastLocationForSub(carrierIds as String, numberMap: numberMap, vehicleMap: vehicleMap, personMap: personMap, routeMap: routeMap, timeMap: timeMap, selCarrier: selectedId as String, lastTime: lastLocTime)
            //            if  (selectedId.intValue ) > 0{
            //                selCarLocList = (SubscriberLocationService.sharedSubLocationService).getLocSetForSelectedCarrier(selectedId as String, lastLocTime: lastLocTime)
            //                            }
            //            else{
            //                (SubscriberLocationService.sharedSubLocationService).syncLastLocationForSubDetails(timeMap)
            //                (SubscriberLocationService.sharedSubLocationService).sublocationDelegate = self
            //            }
        }
    }

    //subscriberlocser delegate method
    func getSubsriberLiveLocation() {
        (ShowLoader.showLoaderSharedInstance).hideLoadingHUD()
        initializeMapData()
    }

    func initializeMapData(){
        // (ShowToast.showToastSharedInstance).showActivityWithMessage()
        let subscriberData = (PMLAppCache.sharedPMLCache).getSubscriberConfig()
        isSchool = ((GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_SchoolBus == subscriberData.organizationType) || (GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_OfficeBus == subscriberData.organizationType) || (GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_Taxi == subscriberData.organizationType))
        isOffice = ((GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_SchoolBus == subscriberData.organizationType) || (GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_OfficeBus == subscriberData.organizationType) || (GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_Taxi == subscriberData.organizationType))
        isTaxi = ((GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_SchoolBus == subscriberData.organizationType) || (GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_OfficeBus == subscriberData.organizationType) || (GlobalConstants.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_Taxi == subscriberData.organizationType))
        //  InitializeActivityAsyncTask().execute();

            self.getInitialData()


    }
        func getInitialData() {
        self.locList.removeAllObjects()
        var data : SubscriberLocationDetails  = SubscriberLocationDetails()
        carrierIdList =  (CodeTypeCodeValueService.sharedcodeTypecodeValService).getAllIdFromAppDB(CodeTypeConstants.CARRIER_CODES) as! NSArray
        carrierIds = ""
        for i in 0 ..< carrierIdList.count{
            if i == carrierIdList.count-1 {
                carrierIds.appendString(carrierIdList[i] as! String)
            }else if i != 0{
                carrierIds.appendString(carrierIdList[i] as! String)
                carrierIds.appendString(",")
            }
        }
        locList = (SubscriberLocationService.sharedSubLocationService).getLastLocDataForCarriers() as! NSMutableArray
        (SubscriberLocationService.sharedSubLocationService).sublocationDelegate = self
        let sortDiscripter = NSSortDescriptor(key:"vehicleDesc", ascending: true)
        let sortedResults: NSArray = locList.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDiscripter])
        locList.removeAllObjects()
        locList = sortedResults.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray


        for i in 0 ..< locList.count{

            data = locList[i] as! SubscriberLocationDetails
            key = data.carrierId!
            numberMap.setObject(data.personPhone!, forKey: key)
            vehicleMap.setObject(data.vehicleDesc!, forKey: key)
            personMap.setObject(data.personDesc!, forKey: key)
            routeMap.setObject(data.routeNumber!, forKey: key)
            if i == 0 {
                timeMap.setObject(data.createdTime!, forKey: data.carrierId!)
            }else if(timeMap.objectForKey(data.carrierId!) !== NSNull() && ((data.createdTime?.longLongValue > timeMap.objectForKey(data.carrierId!)?.longLongValue))){
                timeMap.setObject(data.createdTime!, forKey: data.carrierId!)
            }
            if ((lastLocTime.isEqualToNumber(0)) || (lastLocTime.longLongValue < data.createdTime?.longLongValue))  {
                lastLocTime = data.createdTime!
            }

        }
        if isSchool {
            let sortDiscripter = NSSortDescriptor(key:"vehicleDesc", ascending: true)
            let sortedResults: NSArray = locList.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDiscripter])
            locList.removeAllObjects()
            locList = sortedResults.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

        }else{
            let sortDiscripter = NSSortDescriptor(key:"personDesc", ascending: true)
            let sortedResults: NSArray = locList.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDiscripter])
            locList.removeAllObjects()
            locList = sortedResults.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

        }
        if selectedId .intValue > 0 {
            for i in 0 ..< locList.count {
                let locData = locList[i] as! SubscriberLocationDetails
                if (locData.carrierId == selectedId) {
                    let latLanCoords :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:locData.latitude as! Double , longitude:locData.longitude as! Double)
                    self.centerMapOnLocation(latLanCoords)
                    self.setSingleAnnotation(locData)
                    setButtonsForScrollview(locData.carrierId!)
                }
            }
        }else{
            setTheAnnotations(locList)
            self.setButtonsForScrollview("")
        }

    }



    //    115.315482669664
    //    -175.179858047742
    //    133.003988043541
    //    133.168361358532
    //    8.32069131099509
    //    133.089068653276
    //    -21.9573563525713
    /*------- set Annotations **/
    func setTheAnnotations(annotArray : NSArray) {
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.selectedId = ""
            self.degreeMap.removeAllObjects()
            //var oldLoc = CLLocation()
            var newLoc = CLLocation()
            //        let str = String(format: "%.01f", maxLoc)
            //        maxdist = Double(str)!
                        for annotation in self.liveTrackingMapView.annotations as [MKAnnotation] {
                self.liveTrackingMapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
            }
//        print(annotArray.count)
            for i in 0 ..< annotArray.count{
                let subLocData = annotArray[i] as! SubscriberLocationDetails
                let initialLocation :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:subLocData.latitude as! Double , longitude:subLocData.longitude as! Double)
                // let distanceInMeters = userloc.distanceFromLocation(initialLocation)
                //if distanceInMeters > 0 {
                let subConfig = (SubscriberConfigDBHandler.SubConfigDBSharedInstance).getSubscriberUserDetails()

                let subscriberLocation = CLLocation(latitude: subConfig.busLat as Double , longitude : subConfig.busLng as Double)
                newLoc = initialLocation
                var locationArray = NSArray()
                let placesData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myList") as? NSData
                if let placesData = placesData {
                    locationArray = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(placesData) as? [SubscriberLocationDetails])!
                }
                self.key = subLocData.vehicleDesc!
                if (UiUtils.uiUtilsSharedInstance).getUserDefaultsBool(GlobalConstants.FIRST_TIME_GET_BEARING){
                    self.busDegree = self.getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(subscriberLocation, point2: newLoc)
                    self.degreeMap.setObject(self.busDegree, forKey: self.key)
                    self.lastLocationArray.addObject(subLocData)
                    if i == self.locList.count - 1 {
                        (UiUtils.uiUtilsSharedInstance).updateUserDefaultsBool(GlobalConstants.FIRST_TIME_GET_BEARING, value: false)

                        let placesData1 = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.lastLocationArray)
                        self.lastLocationArray.removeAllObjects()
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(placesData1, forKey: "myList")
                    }
                }else{
                    for i in 0 ..< locationArray.count{
                        let locData = locationArray[i] as! SubscriberLocationDetails
                        if locData.carrierId == subLocData.carrierId {
                            let oldLocation = CLLocation(latitude:locData.latitude as! Double, longitude : locData.longitude as! Double)
                            self.busDegree = self.getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(oldLocation, point2: newLoc)
                            self.degreeMap.setObject(self.busDegree, forKey: self.key)
                        }
                        if i == locationArray.count - 1 {
                            let placesData1 = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.lastLocationArray)
                            self.lastLocationArray.removeAllObjects()
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(placesData1, forKey: "myList")
                        }

                    }

                }

                self.setAnnotationView(subLocData, coords: newLoc)
            }
//        }
        //oldLoc = newLoc
        //                let sourceIndex = oldLoc
        //                let destinationIndex = newLoc
        //
        //              let c1 = sourceIndex.coordinate
        //              let c2 = destinationIndex.coordinate
        //              var a = [c1, c2]
        //              let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
        //              liveTrackingMapView.addOverlay(polyline)



    }

    func setAnnotationView(data : SubscriberLocationDetails ,coords :CLLocation) {
        let locationCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coords.coordinate.latitude, coords.coordinate.longitude)
        pointAnnotation = CustomPointAnnotation(location: locationCoords)
        if isSchool {
            ImageNameStr = "school_bus_marker.png"
        }else if isOffice{
            ImageNameStr = "office_bus_marker.png"
        }else if isTaxi{
            ImageNameStr = "car_marker.png"
        }else{
            ImageNameStr = "onfield_component_default.png"
        }

        pointAnnotation.coordinate = coords.coordinate
        if personMap.valueForKey(data.carrierId!) as? String == "" {
            pointAnnotation.title = "NA"
        }else{
            pointAnnotation.title = personMap.valueForKey(data.carrierId!) as? String
        }
        pointAnnotation.subtitle = data.vehicleDesc
        pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.liveTrackingMapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
    }
```

Comment: Have you minutely observed the syntaxes and steps of map loading methods..?

Comment: Please include some code. Otherwise there is basically no way we can help you for this problem.

Comment: i have set the region, location coords  and delegate correctly but it is zooming out when i try to zoom to some location

Comment: You have a bug in line 278 of your view controller. I can tell that because I'm psychic.

Comment: What do you mean "not working correctly", and "Its coming back into initial state". You're changing the annotations that should be shown but they are reverting? The zoom is reverting? We need details. You also need to post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: This question is a poster child for "How to ask a really bad question on SO." Vague, incomplete description of the problem. No explanation of the structure of your program. No code provided. How do you expect us to be able to help you‽

Comment: @DuncanC Your first comment is gold ahah.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at this [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for best results when using this site.

Comment: i am hit execute this code after every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The reason your mapKit view keeps zooming out is that in the function below is called and keeps "resetting" your region.

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last as CLLocation? else { return }

        let userCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userCenter, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 180, longitudeDelta: 180))
        nameOfMapKitView.setRegion(region, animated: true) // THIS CAUSES MAP TO ZOOM OUT AGAIN

}
```

Edit: As others have said, please post code with your question so we don't have to "guess" the error, luckily i ran into this the other day so I am pretty sure this is what is wrong with your map view.

Comment: i am not use user location thats why i am not using this delegate method